# SugarOrm data display junk

Tags: java, android, sugarorm

when I display the data that display junk data I use listview to display the data.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Button btnSave, btnDelete;
    EditText title, edition;
    ListView mListView;
    ArrayAdapter<Book> adapter;

    Book book = new Book();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        title = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTitle);
        edition = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEdition);

        btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSave);
        btnDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonDelete);

        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        // List<Book> list= Select.from(Book.class).list();
        List<Book> list = Book.listAll(Book.class);

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Book>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + list, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                book = new Book(title.getText().toString(), edition.getText().toString());
                book.save();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + book, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Book book = Book.findById(Book.class, (long) 1);
                book.delete();
            }
        });


    }

}
```

Book.java

```
public class Book  extends SugarRecord<Book>{

    String title;
    String Edition;

    public Book()
    {

    }
    public Book(String title,String Edition)
    {
        this.title=title;
        this.Edition=Edition;
    }
}
```

when I delete the data than it delete also but when display it display junk data how can I display proper data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a custom adapter to render values from your book object. Simplest option would be to implement the toString() method in the Book class. That should fix that.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use  toString() method in order to remove juck values, make sure  to insert single value , because toString() can return only single value

```
import com.orm.SugarRecord;       // package


public class Book  extends SugarRecord{     /// inheritance

String title;                   //var

public  Book()                  //constructor
{
}

public  Book(String title)      //method
{
this.title=title;                 //  this keyword refer current object
}


 public String toString()            // method
 {
 return title;                    //string return value
 }
```

If you have any problem  you can watch this video
    https://youtu.be/lv4QanVZfs4